# Rails 5.2 API ActiveStorage how to get URL paths for multi image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am migrating from paperclip to Rails 5.2 and active storage. I am using rails as API-only.

How to get URL paths for *has_many_attached :images*

This is the code for the single file that works:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
attributes %i[email name username]
....
  attribute :verification_url do
    if object.verification_file.attachment
      URI.join(ActionController::Base.asset_host, rails_blob_path(object.verification_file))
    end
  end
....

end
```

And when I try to do something similar for multi-images I am just getting those images, not their URL.

```
 include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
 attributes :id, :name, :description, :images

 def images
  if object.images.attachments
    object.images.each do |image| 
      URI.join(ActionController::Base.asset_host, rails_blob_path(image))
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: It seems as if the image is the actual url.  `<%= link_to image) %>` , when clicking this link you should get a path on your browser similar to `your_local_host/rails/active_storage/disk/..`

Comment: I am using rails only for API server, and I need to pass those urls through Active Serializer, this solution would probably work on regular rails applications.

Comment: Gotchya, have you tried `rails_blob_url(image)` for the absolute path?

Comment: I'm currently in the process of researching the new active storage feature for rails 5.2 as an upcoming new project for work will require it.  So some of these situations you are facing will surely be helping me out in the coming days.  Can you also try this `rails_blob_path(image, disposition: "attachment", only_path: true)` to see if it generates the absolute path you require? Thanks.

Comment: I am getting the same object as before 

`blob_id
:
4
created_at
:
"2018-05-22T11:21:04.927Z"
id
:
4
name
:
"images"
record_id
:
42
record_type
:
"Dish"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
def images
  return unless object.images.attachments
  image_urls = object.images.map do |image| 
    URI.join(
      ActionController::Base.asset_host, 
      rails_blob_path(image))
  end

  image_urls
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't `image_urls` be an Array? Wouldn't this only ever return the last image in the collection?

Comment: @Jurgen image_urls is an array, .map method is creating it by default.